# Comparing an Integral and a Floating values

Tags: haskell, prime-factoring

So, I am in the process of learning Haskell, and am frequently falling to type/type-classes related errors. Some pretty obvious silly mistakes, and some that make me feel haskell isn't right for me. Anyway, I have this piece of code...

```
pfactors' ps n
    | p > (sqrt n) = []
    | m == 0 = p : (pfactors' ps q)
    | otherwise = pfactors' (tail ps) n where
        p = head ps
        (q, m) = divMod n p

pfactors = pfactors' primes

main = print $ pfactors 14
```

(Some background: the pfactors function is supposed to take a number and return a list of prime numbers, which are the prime factors of the given number. `primes` is an infinite list of prime numbers)

which gives me this error:

```
p47.hs:10:11:
    Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraints:
      `Floating a' arising from a use of `pfactors'' at p47.hs:10:11-26
      `Integral a' arising from a use of `primes' at p47.hs:10:21-26
    Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
      pfactors :: a -> [a] (bound at p47.hs:10:0)
    Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
                  or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
```

Now I understood this is a problem with the `p < (sqrt n)` part, because it is the only part that has anything to do with `Floating`. If I change it to `p < n` everything works fine and I get the correct answer. But I really want to check with the square-root, so how do I do it?

And btw, this is not homework, if it feels like, it is my attempt at solving the 47th problem on projecteuler.net

Thanks for any help.

And, please don't give me the solution to the said project euler problem, I want to do it myself as much as I can :). Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that... well... you can't compare Integral and Floating values :-)  You have to explicitly indicate the conversions between integers and floats.  The `sqrt :: (Floating a) => a -> a` function works with floats, but you're dealing primarily in integers, so you don't get to use it for free.  Try something like this:

```
pfactors' ps n
    | p > (floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n) = []
    | m == 0 = p : (pfactors' ps q)
    | otherwise = pfactors' (tail ps) n where
        p = head ps
        (q, m) = divMod n p
```

Here, we use `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b` to convert from integer to something else, allowing us to use it as the argument to `sqrt`.  Then, we say `floor` to convert our float value back to an integer (note that this rounds down!).

Second, I recommend getting into the habit of adding type signatures to your toplevel declarations.  Not only will it give you a better grasp of the language, but if you don't, you may run foul of the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).

Comment: waw, so much for so little. I tried using `floor $ sqrt`, but I didn't put the `fromIntegral`, need to get used to this stuff i guess :). And yeah, I have to be putting type signatures too :)

Answer (score 5):

I want to provide some additional clarification of what's going on, even though the solution has already been provided.

In particular, type classes are **NOT** types.  You can't have an Integral value or a Floating value.  Those aren't types, they are type classes.  This isn't like object-oriented subtyping.

A signature like `Integral a => a -> a -> a` doesn't mean "a function that takes two Integral arguments, and returns some Integral value."  It means "A function that takes two values of type a, and returns a value of type a.  Also, type a must be an instance of Integral."  The differences between the two are significant. It's very important to remember that both arguments and the return value are the same type.  "a" can't vary its meaning within a type signature.

So what does all this mean?

Well, first of all, there's no a priori requirement that a type can't be an instance of both Integral and Floating.  If you had such a type, no conversions would be necessary.  However, the semantic meaning of each of those type classes makes it hard for a single type to be an instance of both in a meaningful way.

Second, you should be a bit more careful in how you talk about type classes.  They are fundamentally different from object-oriented subtyping.  Because of the conceptual differences, there are also terminological differences.  Being precise with your terminology helps to both understand the differences, and communicate them with others.

So how would I phrase the question, then?  Something like "How do I convert an Integer to an instance of Floating and back?  I need to use the `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a` function on, and compare its result to, Integer values."

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot Carl, I did have the conceptual distinction about types and type classes (I am reading the book "Learn you a Haskell for great good"), but when I said "`Floating` value", I meant "a value with a type that is an instance of `Floating` type class". Still getting used to the terminology :)

Answer (score 0):

You already got your answer, but maybe this helps in avoiding similar problems in the feature:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers

As someone whose background is almost exclusively in dynamically typed languages, I sometimes have the same problem, so I made it a habit to *always* start with the signature when writing a Haskell function. It really does help me in reasoning about what I expect and where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should stop treating Haskell like a dynamic language and start adding type signatures :)

Comment: You certainly don't have to, Haskell's type inference is really good. I just found that it helps me in thinking about my code.